# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) Xcode

Tags: xcode

[This is my code but I when I run the Xcode it gives the error "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)" Any help will be great!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLaCw.png)

Comment: And not more message in Console/Debugguer?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow I would highly advice going through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also it's better to add code here (you can use code formatter) than attaching an image in case someone wants to run the code while trying to answer (it is easier to copy IMHO).